# Why SOA(struct of array) still faster than AOS(array of struct), when access all data of single struct in one loop

Tags: c++, performance, memory

I write a code like below,test performance of soa and aos.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <array>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <istream>
#include <ostream>
#include <random>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>

#define ELE_NUM 50000000

struct SOA{
    std::vector<int> array1;
    std::vector<int> array2;
    std::vector<int> array3;
};

struct AOS{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};


int main(){
    
    std::random_device _rd;
    std::mt19937 rd(_rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> ds(0,100000);
    SOA soa;
    std::vector<AOS> aos(ELE_NUM);
    std::vector<int> rst(ELE_NUM);
    soa.array1.reserve(ELE_NUM);
    soa.array2.reserve(ELE_NUM);
    soa.array3.reserve(ELE_NUM); 
    auto begin_time = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    for(int i = 0 ; i < ELE_NUM;++i){
        aos[i].a = ds(rd);
        aos[i].b = ds(rd);
        aos[i].c = ds(rd);
    }
    auto end_time = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto aos_write_time = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end_time-begin_time);

    begin_time = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    for(int i = 0 ; i < ELE_NUM;++i){
        soa.array1[i] = ds(rd);
        soa.array2[i] = ds(rd);
        soa.array3[i] = ds(rd);
    }
    end_time = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto soa_write_time = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end_time-begin_time);

    begin_time = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    for(int i = 0 ; i < ELE_NUM ; i++){
        rst[i] = aos[i].a +aos[i].b +aos[i].c;
    }
    end_time = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto aos_time = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end_time-begin_time);
    
    //for avoid optimize, output rst
    std::fstream f("tmp.txt",std::iostream::out);
    for(int i = 0 ; i < ELE_NUM ; ++i ) f<<rst[i];
    f<<std::endl;
    begin_time = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    for (int i = 0 ; i < ELE_NUM; i++) {
        rst[i] = soa.array1[i] + soa.array2[i] + soa.array3[i];
    }
    end_time = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto soa_time = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end_time-begin_time);

    for(int i = 0 ; i < ELE_NUM ; ++i ) f<<rst[i];
    f<<std::endl;
    f.close();

    std::cout<<"soa_write_time:"<<soa_write_time.count()<<" ms"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"aos_write_time:"<<aos_write_time.count()<<" ms"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"soa_time:"<<soa_time.count()<<" ms"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"aos_time:"<<aos_time.count()<<" ms"<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

its output result in my pc(windows,i5 13400,compile with g++ -O3):

```
soa_write_time:225 ms
aos_write_time:179 ms
soa_time:28 ms
aos_time:43 ms
```

soa write are always slower than aos.But soa read are always faster than aos.

In my opinion,SOA store one struct data in seperate arrays. when I try to access all data of one struct in one loop,SOA cannot hit cpu cache,so it should be slower than AOS. AOS store a struct data as neighbours,it will hit cpu cache,so AOS will be faster. But this code show a opposite result, why?

Comment: What is `coda`? What is `sturct data`? What is `SOA`? What is `AOS`?

Comment: Using `random_device` inside the loops isn't a great idea. Use a deterministic PRNG, like `std::mt19937` and seed it equally for both the SOA and AOS tests. Also, since the result of the operations are not observed anywhere a compiler may optimize away parts or all of them.

Comment: @StephenQuan sorry for my spelling  error,I have revised them.

Comment: @TedLyngmo close result after random print data.

Comment: Caches are large.  When you read a single element from your vector, that's going to bring an entire cache line from that location, so the next several elements will be in the cache ready to go.

Comment: @Dreams You would need to print it after each test though. Right now it could disregard everything before the last test.  Use a proper tool for benchmarking. https://quick-bench.com/ is nice.

Comment: You're not using an *array* of struct. You're using a *vector* of struct. Change the vector to an actual array and you'll see the speed difference diminish a lot. Why that is I can't say exactly, but seemed to produce constant results for me.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen  std::array will out of stack on my pc with such large size array.

Comment: Use dynamic memory allocation

Comment: Which means : std::make_unique<std::array<...>>

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen It so weird to use array to create a dynamic array for modern C++.Anyway it indeed diminish.

Comment: @TimRoberts Aos also make use of all cache line.What cause the difference.